# Single page problem when permalink type changed

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, single

I have a custom post type which i create and works perfect without any problem, its a team page to show some members in a company, also i created a single-team page to show more details about each member.

The problem is when i use Default Permalinks works without any problem, but when use Post name permalink a got 404 error page not found.

i hope i didn't miss anything to make this work.

Comment: Does your theme have other custom post types in it or any other plugins you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make sure that your .HTaccess is writable with necessary permissions that includes the Following as I suspect that WP is not able to alter it :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: actually im using local server

Comment: Ok, but still can you check if there are suitable permissions for altering the Htaccess, this is important if you want to use permaliminks.

Comment: Just Upload my files on working server, not using local and see the permisions as @spraveenitpro say, now it's working.